# Should I use "also" or "too"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, too-also

I'm a German native speaker and sometimes I'm confused about how to use the above-mentioned  words.

For example,

> This idea is good, and that idea is good too

Is this OK, or should I use, instead of *too*,  the word *also*?

Please give some examples and explanations.

Comment: There is often a comma placed just before a sentence-ending _too_; e.g.: _This idea is good and that idea is good, too_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when *too* is used at the end of the clause, [it means 'also' or 'as well'.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/too?q=too) So, ***also = too*** in that way.

> *When I've finished painting the bathroom, I'm going to do the kitchen **too/also/as well**.*

The preposition 'to' is entirely different. Don't use it to mean 'too/as well/also' in **any** case.

*'to'* has many meanings and uses. Refer any dictionary  ***<del>too</del> to*** find that!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "to" (!) after "refer" in the last sentence?

Comment: @steve no. You refer dictionary and a person with no knowledge is refer to as a fool.

Comment: Perhaps this depends on dialect? In British English, it would be "refer to" in this context.

Comment: In American English as well, you "refer **to** a dictionary".

Comment: I agree; we omit the word _to_ when the verb is _reference_ (e.g., _reference any dictionary to find out_), but we generally include a _to_ when the verb is _refer_ (e.g., _refer to the manual for more information_).